# How to sort numbers that are separated by comma

Tags: excel, sorting

I want to sort  a list  of  number that have a comma "," as  thousands separator  from  biggest to smallest.  how can I do this ? is there a better  was to order  the mailbox usage   From largest  to  smallest?

Example

```
Mailbox Usage                        Helper 
952.2 MB (998,459,360 bytes)         998,459,360 
950.9 MB (997,059,715 bytes)         997,059,715 
945.7 MB (991,650,962 bytes)         991,650,962 
92.85 GB (99,701,179,524 bytes)      99,701,179,524 
938.9 MB (984,498,622 bytes)         984,498,622 
936 MB (981,481,636 bytes)           981,481,636 
935.5 MB (980,976,385 bytes)         980,976,385 
94.19 MB (98,769,194 bytes)          98,769,194 
91.46 GB (98,204,797,816 bytes)      98,204,797,816 
91.02 GB (97,730,526,294 bytes)      97,730,526,294 
90.99 GB (97,701,587,415 bytes)      97,701,587,415 
919.3 MB (963,922,906 bytes)         963,922,906 
92.5 MB (96,988,172 bytes)           96,988,172 
92.34 MB (96,822,749 bytes)          96,822,749 
90.05 GB (96,687,167,126 bytes)      96,687,167,126 
89.85 GB (96,477,143,313 bytes)      96,477,143,313 
89.65 GB (96,259,776,951 bytes)      96,259,776,951
```

Comment: Highlight all the numbers in the helper column and change the format to Number (it might be set to "General" or some other setting). This setting in on the Home tab near the middle.

Comment: I have tried  making the  Helper column  as number  but  sorting still off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert text to number with formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))
```

then sort

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much  this worked like  a charm !